# Different netty versions from the same gatling depency

Tags: scala, maven, netty, gatling

I've been running the gatling performance tests and have noticed that one of our APIs is throwing the following error at the `HttpProtocolBuilder` stage:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DNT
    at io.gatling.http.HeaderNames$.<clinit>(Headers.scala:44)
    at io.gatling.http.HttpDsl.$init$(HttpDsl.scala:52)
    at io.gatling.http.Predef$.<clinit>(Predef.scala:19)
```

I suspect this is due to a mismatch in dependency versions and sure enough I noticed that the working APIs are using this netty version

```
[INFO] |  |  +- io.gatling:gatling-http:jar:3.7.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.gatling:gatling-http-client:jar:3.7.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.65.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.65.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.65.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.65.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.65.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.39.Final:test
```

Whereas the failing one is using

```
[INFO] |  |  +- io.gatling:gatling-http:jar:3.7.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.gatling:gatling-http-client:jar:3.7.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.31.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.31.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.31.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.31.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.31.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.20.Final:test
```

Does anyone know why the APIs might be using different netty versions when they come from the exact same gatling library? And how to potentially fix it?

Can't share much more information due to it being a work project.

Cheers,
Kris

Comment: If you look at the dependency tree, you should find another library  pulling netty and "forcing" the version. Upgrade all libraries and/or use a dependency management block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why the APIs might be using different netty versions when they come from the exact same gatling library?

No idea what you mean here.

My2cents: Gatling is not the only library in your project pulling netty. Some other library, or some dependencyManagement block, force a downgrade to a very old version (4.1.31 was released 4 years ago).

Don't downgrade, upgrade instead. If you have a library that pulls a dependency from 4 years ago, there's a very good chance it's super old too.

Comment: Cheers, will run the mvn dependency tree and see

Comment: marking the answer as correct as it was another dependency that was forcing it. I did however not manage to find it so just forced the 4.1.65 using netty-bom. All the ones in the dependency tree seemed to point to .65 so no idea where the .31 was getting forced from. This solved the NoSuchFieldError.